# Loading Test - Address already in use

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

Good morning colleagues.

I have jmeter test scenario I must run on my back-end service. If I use 1 or ~50 Threads(users) in one time there is no problem. But when I try to set more than 50 users I got an errors like this :

`java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

How can I fix it ?

jMeter version 4.0

java 10.0.1

OS Windows 10 64

Full Log :

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:199)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
>       at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.run(JMeterThreadParallel.java:61)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks.

Comment: What JMeter, java and OS version do you use?
Could you attach jmeter full log?

Comment: @VadimYangunaev updated question

Comment: and the same issue with JMeter 5.0?

Comment: @VadimYangunaev You think jMeter 5 will be better than 4 ? ok I'll try.

Comment: @VadimYangunaev the problem is still here. first I got 500 Code from Back-end and than Connection reset message. may be Back-end cannot open new Connections ?

Comment: What is your application server? If you get 500 internal server error, it should log it.

Comment: @VadimYangunaev yes indeed, we detected some server problems. but I want to clarify - is this message "Connection reset" thrown because timeout exceeded ? Because I did set timeout all of my HTTP Requests as 60sec but on "Aggregate Graph" I see max equal value 83sec.       https://imgur.com/a/kSaUFUh

Comment: I do not see the "Address already in use" from the title anywhere in the content of the question. Why is it in the title?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is an issue with application under test and it does not configured properly to handle this load.
Check:

1. Application server logs.
2. Open your application in the browser, while it under the load testing - does it work properly?

Comment: 1. - did you mean  `Access Log Sampler` ? 2 - which browser you are talking about ?

Comment: No, I mean it does not looks like JMeter issue, but the application. Because if for 50 threads it works ok.
1. So, any kind of logs from your service. Do you have access to them? And what kind of back end service is it?
2. And any case to get responsce from your service outside of JMeter.

Comment: I test REST service and Requests, which failed with "Connection reset" message are never write to log.

Comment: What is your application server where you host REST service?

Answer (score 2):

Please implement the below steps, your "Connection reset" problem will be resolved.

- Change "Implementation" of all your HTTP Request samplers to
  HttpClient4. The easiest way of doing it is using HTTP Request
  Defaults configuration element.
- Please add the following properties in user.properties file which
  located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

> httpclient4.retrycount=1
>   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

- Add the next line to hc.parameters file (same location, JMeter's /bin
  folder)

> http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

- Please restart your JMeter

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help. I still got Connection reset messages after restarting jMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I had message "address already used" in JMeter 5.1 (Windows 10) when I tested Java Spring app. It helped me a lot: [enter link description here](https://evgeniyosipov.blogspot.com/2015/04/tcpip-windows-7.html)

(No need reload Windows and stop JMeter and application - You can play with parameters on fly.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Jensi.

Below solution worked for me but also need to make changes to the slave machine along with Master machine.

"Please implement the below steps, your "Connection reset" problem will be resolved.

Change "Implementation" of all your HTTP Request samplers to HttpClient4. The easiest way of doing it is using HTTP Request Defaults configuration element.

Please add the following properties in user.properties file which located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

Add the next line to hc.parameters file (same location, JMeter's /bin folder)
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

Please restart your JMeter"